# how can i create webRTC with 2 pc's?

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I am completely new in WebRTC concept in PC's .  I want to check and working of a simple WebRTC concept . I searched lot of document i got 2 source code . One is **SimpleWebRTC** https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC & another is **easyrtc** https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc. I don't know which one is better ? Which one should i take to implement WebRTC ? Any suggestions ?

what about **openwebrtc**  ? can i do openwebrtc in PC's ?

Any related Document ?

Comment: I think you should start from here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Comment: thanks . let me know when i face any difficulties .